# Conversion error in jdbc store mapping but query works fine in Management Studio

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have this stored procedure:

```
USE [MYDB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update]
    ( @IN_ID_RECORD             nvarchar(2)
    , @IN_COD_IST               nvarchar(5)
    , @IN_COD_SOC_GEST          char(5)
    , @IN_COD_PTF               nvarchar(2)
    , @IN_COD_LIN               nvarchar(2)
    , @IN_COD_GEST              nvarchar(5)
    , @IN_DAT_RIF               nvarchar(10)    
    , @IN_DAT_VAL               nvarchar(10)
    , @IN_ID_UPLOAD             nvarchar(2)
    , @IN_COD_CAUS              nvarchar(6)
    , @IN_VAL_COD_TIT           nvarchar(30)
    , @IN_DIV_RIF               nvarchar(3)
    , @IN_IMP                   numeric(25,3)
    , @IN_IMP_RATEO             decimal(18,3)
    , @IN_QTA                   numeric(18,5)
    , @IN_PRZ                   decimal(21, 10) = 0
    , @IN_FX                    decimal(18, 9)
    , @IN_COD_MER               nvarchar(20)
    , @IN_NOTE                  nvarchar(100))

AS      

    DECLARE @@SQL                   nvarchar(max)
        , @@TABLE_NAME              nvarchar(45)
        , @@WHERE                   nvarchar(max)
        , @@DAT_RIF                 smalldatetime   
        , @@DAT_VAL                 smalldatetime

    SET NOCOUNT ON   

    SET @@TABLE_NAME = 'UPLOAD_MOVTIT'
    SET @@TABLE_NAME = @@TABLE_NAME + '_' + @IN_COD_SOC_GEST 

    SET @@WHERE = ' WHERE'

    IF (LTRIM(@IN_ID_RECORD) <> '')
        SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND ID_RECORD = '+@IN_ID_RECORD

    IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_IST) <> '')       
        SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_IST = @IN_COD_IST'

    IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_SOC_GEST) <> '')
        SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_SOC_GEST = @IN_COD_SOC_GEST'  

    --IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_PTF) <> '')
    --  SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_PTF = @IN_COD_PTF'    

    --IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_LIN) <> '')     
    --  SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_LIN = @IN_COD_LIN'

    --IF (LTRIM(@IN_COD_GEST) <> '')        
    --  SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND COD_GEST = @IN_COD_GEST'  

    IF (LTRIM(@IN_DAT_RIF) <> '')
        SET @@DAT_RIF = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, LTRIM(@IN_DAT_RIF), 103) 

    IF (LTRIM(@IN_DAT_VAL) <> '')
        SET @@DAT_VAL = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, LTRIM(@IN_DAT_VAL), 103) 

    IF (LTRIM(@IN_ID_UPLOAD) <> '')
        SET @@WHERE = @@WHERE + ' AND ID_UPLOAD = '+@IN_ID_UPLOAD   

    IF (@@WHERE <> ' WHERE')        
        SET @@WHERE = REPLACE(@@WHERE, ' WHERE AND', ' WHERE')
    ELSE
        SET @@WHERE = ''

    BEGIN
        SET @@SQL = 'UPDATE ' + @@TABLE_NAME 
            + ' SET COD_PTF = @IN_COD_PTF
                , COD_LIN = @IN_COD_LIN
                , COD_GEST = @IN_COD_GEST
                , DAT_RIF = @@DAT_RIF 
                , DAT_VAL = @@DAT_VAL
                , COD_CAUS = @IN_COD_CAUS
                , VAL_COD_TIT = @IN_VAL_COD_TIT
                , DIV_RIF = @IN_DIV_RIF
                , IMP = @IN_IMP
                , IMP_RATEO = @IN_IMP_RATEO
                , QTA = @IN_QTA
                , PRZ = @IN_PRZ
                , FX = @IN_FX
                , COD_MER = @IN_COD_MER
                , NOTE = @IN_NOTE
                , DAT_ULT_MOD = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ' + @@WHERE 

    END

    PRINT @@sql

    EXEC sp_executesql @@SQL
                        , N'@IN_ID_RECORD nvarchar(2), @IN_COD_IST  nvarchar(5), @IN_COD_SOC_GEST char(5), @IN_COD_PTF nvarchar(2), @IN_COD_LIN nvarchar(2), @IN_COD_GEST nvarchar(5), @IN_DAT_RIF nvarchar(10), @IN_DAT_VAL nvarchar(10), @IN_COD_CAUS nvarchar(6), @IN_VAL_COD_TIT nvarchar(30), @IN_DIV_RIF  nvarchar(3), @IN_ID_UPLOAD nvarchar(2), @IN_IMP numeric(25,3), @IN_IMP_RATEO decimal(18,3), @IN_QTA numeric(18,5), @IN_PRZ  decimal(21, 10), @IN_FX decimal(18, 9), @IN_COD_MER nvarchar(20), @IN_NOTE nvarchar(100), @@DAT_RIF smalldatetime, @@DAT_VAL smalldatetime'
                        , @IN_ID_RECORD, @IN_COD_IST, @IN_COD_SOC_GEST, @IN_COD_PTF, @IN_COD_LIN, @IN_COD_GEST, @IN_DAT_RIF, @IN_DAT_VAL, @IN_COD_CAUS, @IN_VAL_COD_TIT, @IN_DIV_RIF, @IN_ID_UPLOAD, @IN_IMP, @IN_IMP_RATEO, @IN_QTA, @IN_PRZ, @IN_FX, @IN_COD_MER, @IN_NOTE,@@DAT_RIF, @@DAT_VAL


RETURN @@ERROR
```

And I've mapped it as follows:

```
public class UploadMovTitUpdateStoredProcedure extends StoredProcedure {

    private static final String SPROC_NAME = "sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update";

    public UploadMovTitUpdateStoredProcedure(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        super(jdbcTemplate, SPROC_NAME);    


        declareParameter(new SqlReturnResultSet("result", new RowMapper<UploadMovTitSave>() {

            @Override
            public UploadMovTitSave mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                UploadMovTitSave movTit = new UploadMovTitSave();

                return movTit;
            }
        }));

            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_ID_RECORD", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_IST", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_SOC_GEST", Types.CHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_ID_UPLOAD", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_PTF", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_LIN", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_GEST", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_DAT_RIF", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_DAT_VAL", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_CAUS", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_VAL_COD_TIT", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_DIV_RIF", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_IMP", Types.NUMERIC));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_IMP_RATEO", Types.DECIMAL));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_QTA", Types.NUMERIC));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_PRZ", Types.DECIMAL));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_FX", Types.DECIMAL));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_COD_MER", Types.VARCHAR));
            declareParameter(new SqlParameter("IN_NOTE", Types.VARCHAR));

            compile();

    }

}
```

The "dao" that calls the stored procedure is as follows:

```
public UploadMovTitSave updateMovTitDetail(UploadMovTitSave entity) {
        UploadMovTitUpdateStoredProcedure sproc = new UploadMovTitUpdateStoredProcedure(jdbcTemplate);
        HashMap<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
        DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        symbols.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
        String pattern = "#,##0.0#";
        DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern, symbols);
        decimalFormat.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        try {
        params.put("IN_ID_RECORD", entity.getIdRecord());
        params.put("IN_COD_IST", (entity.getCodIst()!=null ? entity.getCodIst() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_COD_SOC_GEST", (entity.getCodSocGest()!=null ? entity.getCodSocGest() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_COD_PTF", (entity.getCodPtf()!=null ? entity.getCodPtf() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_COD_LIN", (entity.getCodLin()!=null ? entity.getCodLin() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_COD_GEST", (entity.getCodGest()!=null ? entity.getCodGest() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_DAT_RIF", (entity.getDatRif()!=null ? entity.getDatRif().trim() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_DAT_VAL", (entity.getDatVal()!=null ? entity.getDatVal().trim() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_ID_UPLOAD", entity.getIdUpload());
        params.put("IN_COD_CAUS", (entity.getCodCaus()!=null ? entity.getCodCaus() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_VAL_COD_TIT", (entity.getValCodTit()!=null ? entity.getValCodTit() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_DIV_RIF", (entity.getDivRif()!=null ? entity.getDivRif() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_IMP", (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse((String)entity.getImp()));
        params.put("IN_IMP_RATEO", (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse((String)entity.getImpRateo()));
        params.put("IN_QTA", (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse((String)entity.getQta()));
        params.put("IN_PRZ", (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse((String)entity.getPrz()));
        params.put("IN_FX", (BigDecimal) decimalFormat.parse((String)entity.getFx()));
        params.put("IN_COD_MER", (entity.getCodMer()!=null ? entity.getCodMer() : EMPTY_STRING));
        params.put("IN_NOTE", (entity.getNote()!=null ? entity.getNote() : EMPTY_STRING));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            log.error("Couldn't parse BigDecimals", e);
        }
        log.error("updateMovTitDetail - parametri input : " + params.toString());
        Map<String, Object> results = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        try{
            results = sproc.execute(params);
        }catch(DataIntegrityViolationException ex){
            log.error(ex.getMessage());
            log.error(ex.getStackTrace().toString());
        }


        UploadMovTitSave movTit = (UploadMovTitSave) results.get("result");


        return movTit;
    }
```

When I run the stored procedure from SQL Server Management Studio with the same parameters passed from the front end the stored procedure returns 0, so no errors.

Example of this execution:

```
USE [mydb]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update]
        @IN_ID_RECORD = N'44',
        @IN_COD_IST = N'0',
        @IN_COD_SOC_GEST = N'90000',
        @IN_COD_PTF = N'20',
        @IN_COD_LIN = N'22',
        @IN_COD_GEST = N'00222',
        @IN_DAT_RIF = N'14/06/2017',
        @IN_DAT_VAL = N'18/04/2017',
        @IN_ID_UPLOAD = N'37',
        @IN_COD_CAUS = N'S',
        @IN_VAL_COD_TIT = N'IE00B1W4R501',
        @IN_DIV_RIF = N'USD',
        @IN_IMP = 1022924.19,
        @IN_IMP_RATEO = 0.00,
        @IN_QTA = 66000.00,
        @IN_PRZ = 15.50,
        @IN_FX = 1.07,
        @IN_COD_MER = N' ',
        @IN_NOTE = N' '

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

But when I run it from the software, I get a `dataintegrytiviolationexception` with this message:

```
CallableStatementCallback; SQL [{call sp_UPLOAD_MOVTIT_Update(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}]; Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Conversion failed when converting character string to smalldatetime data type.
```

I've found there's one parameter switched IN_COD_GEST is printed out instead of IN_DAT_RIF when i print the parameter in the stored procedure..

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the order in which parameters were declared, the parameters as to be declared in the same order they're actually put in the params list